# Check for, copy, and update files

Tags: c#, file-copying

Not sure if I'm missing stuff when copying files.

Think code works. I'm looking for input on what I might not be thinking about.

```
        if (File.Exists(docmain1) == true && File.Exists(docmain2) == true)
        {
            if (File.Exists(docmain1destination) == false)
            {
                File.Copy(docmain1, docmain1destination);
            }

            if (File.Exists(docmain2) == false)
            {
                File.Copy(docmain2, docmain2destination);
            }

            if (File.Exists(docmain1destination) == true)
            {
                if (!Locked(docmain1destination))
                {
                    DateTime datemod1 = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(docmain1);
                    DateTime datemod2 = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(docmain1destination);
                    if (datemod1 > datemod2)
                    {
                        File.Copy(docmain1, docmain1destination);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (File.Exists(docmain2destination) == true)
            {
                if (!Locked(docmain2destination))
                {
                    DateTime datemod1 = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(docmain2);
                    DateTime datemod2 = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(docmain2destination);
                    if (datemod1 > datemod2)
                    {
                        File.Copy(docmain2, docmain2destination);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm checking files that are on one spot to a location in another spot.  If the file isn't there, copy it.  If The file is newer, overwrite it.  Syncing, basically. I'm hoping for input from others if I'm missing any critical things for a process like this.  Thank you.

Comment: Copying docmain2 to docmain2destination might prove troublesome when you're only doing that logic if docmain2 _doesn't_ exist.

Comment: You can probably avoid doing things like myVar == true or myVar2 == false. Instead you can do if(myVar && !myVar2) etc. (it may help with readability)

Comment: GetLastWriteTime is not guaranteed to be correct, someone else could change the files while doing what you are doing. In order to protect against that you would need to implement file watchers or some sort of lock logic. If doing locks, make sure to use a try, finally statement so that it almost guarantees unlocking the file if anything goes wrong.